# How to use join table (ManyToMany relation) in queryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a bidirectional ManyToMany relation : Team <=> Championship with a championships_teams join table.

I would like getting all Teams and order by Teams who are in a specific championship first.

A simple sql query to get this can be : (in Mysql null come first)

```
select * 
from team left join championships_teams
            on id=team_id
            and championship_id=:specific_id
order by championship_id desc
```

I have try to do it by using query builder without success.
Can i do this type of query by using query builder without mapping championships_teams as an entity ?

Comment: Seems not to be possible [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9890540/3497667). I can't use native query because I want to use query in a form in 'query_builder' option. I had to find a dql query who order my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage my trouble : order by a query with null value to use the result in a form.

1. We can't access to relation table through DQL : [How do you join two tables in Doctrine2 using Query Builder if the table relationships are not setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890540/how-do-you-join-two-tables-in-doctrine2-using-query-builder-if-the-table-relatio/9892889#9892889). But i can't use native query because i want to get a QueryBuilder object to use it in an entity form.
2. Making an sql query who be in compliance with DQL.

   ```
   SELECT t.*,IFNULL(c.year,0) as year
   FROM Team t LEFT JOIN championships_teams ct 
           ON t.id = ct.team_id 
       LEFT JOIN Championship c 
           ON c.id = ct.championship_id 
           AND c.id = 76 
   WHERE e.league_id = 1
   ORDRE BY year;
   ```
3. Passing through the error `Expected argument of type "object or array", "string" given`  by using HIDDEN word : [How can I order by NULL in DQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652034/how-can-i-order-by-null-in-dql/23007669#23007669). To finally have my DQL query :

   ```
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')        
               ->leftJoin('t.championships', 'c',Expr\Join::WITH,'c.id = :champ_id' )
               ->setParameter('champ_id', $champ->getId())
               ->addSelect('IFNULL(-c.year,0) as HIDDEN year')
               ->where('t.league=:league_id')      
               ->setParameter('league_id', $champ->getLeague())
               ->addorderBy('year')
               ->addorderBy('t.nom');
   return $qb;
   ```

I 'm figuring that my question was not well formulated. Hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to this question - [symfony2 doctrine findBy id in arrayCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722926/symfony2-doctrine-findby-id-in-arraycollection/22723602)

It seems to be a similar issue. You need to use 'MEMBER OF' modifier.